# python bottle with beaker.middleware

Tags: python, bottle, beaker

I want to integrate python beaker.middleware with bottle mvc. This(https://github.com/cavillingelite/bottle-mvc-mod_wsgi) is the configured version of bottle micro framework as MVC. I can run this(http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html) coding but no idea how to integrate this with bottle MVC

Comment: I am still searching a way to do this stuff. Is there anyone who know how to solve this matter. Pleas help me...

Comment: One of the ways you can improve your chances of getting help is maintaining a high acceptance rating.

Answer (score 0):

You might be over thinking it.  If you are loading beaker as middleware, then there is a request.environ.get('beaker.session') dict that acts like the interface to beaker.

I would setup a user class, use a login decorator on secure routes, and then load the user object before you render the template.  In the user object you can just do something like this:

```
self.session = request.environ.get('beaker.session')
self.__dict__.update(self.session)
```

Now just calling user.key will result in anything saved in the beaker session.  If you have autosave turned on in the beaker config, you can then just assign values to the self.session dict, and it will store them in the beaker session.

It really is as easy that.  I am currently using beaker/bottle/redis and it works great.